# Overlapping elements

Tags: css, overlap

On this site http://nutritiousinfo.com I am trying to get the menu navigation element to overlap the header. I tried changing the top margin of the menu to -35px and it looked fine until I refreshed it and it jumped back down again. Here is my CSS for the headers and menus sections:

```
#header {
    background: url(http://nutritiousinfo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Header.png);
    width: 960px; 
    height: 120px;
    margin: 10px auto 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0px #BBBBBB; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px #BBBBBB;
    z-index: -1;
    }



#subnav .wrap {
    background: url(http://nutritiousinfo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/NewNav.png);
    width: 960px;
    height: 70px;
    margin: -30px auto 0;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top: 0px solid #111111;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0px #BBBBBB; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px #BBBBBB;
    z-index: 999999;
    }
```

Comment: Try making a minimal test case in jsfiddle.

Comment: Sorry - I am not sure exactly what you mean.. I am a bit of a newbie to all this :-(

Comment: You have a bunch of code. Try making a simpler example in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Like this? I think its these two bits that I need to fix?

Comment: That's better but a jsfiddle would still help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Vc4yb/ like this? Sorry if I am a bit slow - but we all have to start somewhere..

Answer (score 0):

try replacing your actual margin with this:

```
#subnav .wrap {
   margin: -35px auto 0px auto;
}

#subnav ul {
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0 !important;
   padding: 0 !important;
}

ul {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks  -tried it but it didnt change. Weird thing is if I look at "inspect element" it jumps up and looks right. Then when I refresh it jumps back down again.

Comment: I also see that you didn't reset your css, because there are user agent styles present...

Comment: did you try using css reset? try adding new lines from answer to it because user agent style is still present.